# Comparison script

Tags: sh

I am new in shell scripting and I need help. I have two strings :

```
Expected Dates: 12/17/2012 12/18/2012 12/19/2012 12/20/2012 12/21/2012 12/22/2012 12/23/2012
Eimx/MDW Dates: 12/17/2012 12/18/2012 12/19/2012 12/20/2012 12/21/2012 12/22/2012
```

I want to compare them and displaying the missing data.

I want to to a .sh script for that, how can I do it?

Comment: Are this strings in the same file?

Comment: yes the string are in the same file

Comment: your example looks like the easy case. Is it possible that 12/18/2012 would be missing from 2nd line, while all other dates are there? AND will that leave a "hole" in the line, or will the blank space still be at the end of the line. Don't answer as a comment, please update (edit link) your question and use the `{}` formatting tool at the top of the input box to indent your examples as code samples. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not at all well defined, but perhaps something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

s1='Expected Dates: 12/17/2012 12/18/2012 12/23/2012'
s2='Eimx/MDW Dates: 12/17/2012 12/18/2012'
s1=${s1#*:}  # Trim the header (or start the loop in awk at i=3 )
s2=${s2#*:}

printf "$s1\n$s2\n" | awk  '
    NR==1 {for( i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[$i]=1 }
    NR==2 {for( i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if( ! a[$i] ) print $i; delete a[$i]; }}
    END{ for( i in a) print i}'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can you explain me in details the code please ? Thanks a lot for help again :)

Comment: @luliana  What details need explaining?  Two strings are assigned.  The text up to and including the first `:` is removed.  The two strings are printed as separate lines and piped to `awk`.  While reading the first line, awk builds an array.  While reading the second line, any date that does not appear in the array is printed while those in the array are deleted.  At the end, anything left in the array is printed.

Comment: Hello, thanks for help.I understand from a[$i]=1  that every position for the element from the array becames 1.At the and the first line is inverted  meaning the '12/17/2012 12/18/2012 12/23/2012' '12/23/'becames '12/23/2012 12/18/2012  12/17/2012' .Did i understood ok? And if  yes, why this inversion is necesarry ?

Comment: @luliana The 'inversion' is merely a consequence of the fact that the awk array is printed back in a pseudo-random order.  If order matters, an associative array is not sufficient without extra information to maintain that order.